# Getting node information from chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

Is it possible to easily access the information about the node (similar to `knife node show`) from a recipe without running knife through the "execute" resource? I would like to do this in order to add information about the current runlist and maybe some more details regarding the node into [motd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)) for convenience.

Comment: Yes, look at the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/e21909ae01533883e27c87b15783c3549fed0d9b/lib/chef/node.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for the run_list, if you do not care about order, the most straight forward way would likely be to get this from the Ohai attributes.

```
node['recipes']
node['roles']
```

See: http://docs.getchef.com/ohai.html

If you do care about order, then you may have to operate off of the node object.

```
runlist = node.run_list
```

Which may not be as apparent from the docs.

You can access the rest of the node information in a similar manner.